# Yii 1.x email validator and localhost addresses

Tags: yii, validation, email-validation

Default, build-in Yii e-mail validator fails on e-mails like `superuser@localhost` -- treats them as not valid.

Is this intentional (reason?) or is it a bug in Yii?

Comment: It's more of an oversight, I believe. In most real-world applications, you're not going to use a localhost email for anything, unless hardcoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for this case, you have to bulid your own pattern.

```
public function rules() {
        return array(
           array("email","patern","your regex for validation","message" => "Email is not correct")
        )
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CEmailValidator#allowName-detail